# rxswift bind(onNext: VS subscribe(onNext:

Tags: rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have 2 questions:

1. What difference between 'bind(onNext:' and 'subscribe(onNext:'?

```swift
struct Info {
    var index: Int?
    var data: String?
}

let infoData: BehaviorRelay<Info> = BehaviorRelay<Info>(value: Info())
var osInfo: Observable<String> { return self.infoData.map({ return $0.data }).distinctUntilChanged() }

osInfo.bind { (target) in
    print("bind!")
    }.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

osInfo.subscribe { (target) in
    print("subscribe!")
    }
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

2. a has no asObservable(), but well executable. What is difference a and b?

```swift
a. var osInfo: Observable<String> { return self.infoData.map({ return $0.data }).distinctUntilChanged() }
b. var osInfo: Observable<String> { return self.infoData.asObservable().map({ return $0.data }).distinctUntilChanged() }
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## What is the difference between 'bind(onNext:' and 'subscribe(onNext:'?

If we check implementation of `bind(...)` we found that it does nothing else but just uses `subscribe(...)` underhood and crashes in Debug with error:

```swift
/**
Subscribes an element handler to an observable sequence. 

In case error occurs in debug mode, `fatalError` will be raised.
In case error occurs in release mode, `error` will be logged.

- parameter onNext: Action to invoke for each element in the observable sequence.
- returns: Subscription object used to unsubscribe from the observable sequence.
*/
public func bind(onNext: @escaping (E) -> Void) -> Disposable {
    return subscribe(onNext: onNext, onError: { error in
        rxFatalErrorInDebug("Binding error: \(error)")
    })
}
```

By using `bind(onNext)` you can express that the stream should never emit an error and you are interested only in item events.

So you should use `subscribe(onNext:...)` when you are interested in error / complete / disposed events and `bind(onNext...)` otherwise. But since it is part of `RxCocoa` and not `RxSwift` I usually use `subscribe` everywhere.

## a has no asObservable(), but well executable. What is the difference between a and b?

`map(...)` is a function declared on `ObservableType` and returns a new `Observable`

Let's start from `ObservableType`.
`ObservableType` is a protocol that requires only one method: `subscribe(...)`, this allows it to create a default implementation of `func asObservable()`.
For you it means that you can create an `Observable` from any type that conforms to `ObservableType`.

```swift
/// Represents a push style sequence.
public protocol ObservableType : ObservableConvertibleType {
    func subscribe<O: ObserverType>(_ observer: O) -> Disposable where O.E == E
}
extension ObservableType {
    /// Default implementation of converting `ObservableType` to `Observable`.
    public func asObservable() -> Observable<E> {
        // temporary workaround
        //return Observable.create(subscribe: self.subscribe)
        return Observable.create { o in
            return self.subscribe(o)
        }
    }
}
```

So each time you call `asObservable()` underhood RxSwift just creates a new `Observable` wrapper around your stream.

And if you check the source of `BehaviourRelay` you will find that it conforms to `ObservableType` as well. So you can create `Observable` from it anytime:

```swift
public final class BehaviorRelay<Element>: ObservableType { ... }
```

Now let's check `map` function:

```swift
extension ObservableType {

    /**
     Projects each element of an observable sequence into a new form.

     - seealso: [map operator on reactivex.io](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html)

     - parameter transform: A transform function to apply to each source element.
     - returns: An observable sequence whose elements are the result of invoking the transform function on each element of source.

     */
    public func map<R>(_ transform: @escaping (E) throws -> R)
        -> Observable<R> {
        return self.asObservable().composeMap(transform)
    }
}
```

As expected, `map` just calls `asObservable()` inside and operates on a new `Observable`.

If we "unwrap" `map` call we will get:

```swift
var osInfoA: Observable<String> {
    return infoData
        .asObservable()
        .composeMap { $0.data }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
}
var osInfoB: Observable<String> {
    return infoData
        .asObservable()
        .asObservable()
        .composeMap { $0.data }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
}
```

Sure it will not compile since `composeMap` is an internal function but you get the main idea.
Calling `asObservable` before other operators is redundant (most operators defined on `ObservableType`) and just adds a small overhead.